# ScrollIntoView method doesn't work on my horizontal ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I made a horizontal ListBox, filled it with bound data and set its default item which is "outside" of the screen. After that, I called the ScrollIntoView method, but nothing happens. What have I done wrong?

Related part of my XAML (I think the problem is somewhere here):

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

And C# code:

```
reservationsListBox.SelectedIndex = 40;
reservationsListBox.ScrollIntoView(reservationsListBox.Items[reservationsListBox.SelectedIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ControlTemplate the ScrollViewer needs the x:Name="ScrollViewer".

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

Otherwise the ScrollIntoView function cannot find the viewer to scroll.

Comment: I tried your solution and for first time it didn't do anything. After, I called a reservationsList.UpdateLayout() right before the reservationsListBox.ScrollIntoView part. Now, it scrolls my listbox to "somewhere" (closer to the selected item), but I still can't see the selected item, because its still outside of the screen.

Comment: That's something else beyond the snippet you included here. My guess is that the ListBox itself is larger than the screen. ScrollIntoView will scroll the item into the ListBox (probably at the bottom) but doesn't force the ListBox onto screen.